# "Projection of metric" vs. "projection of curvatures"

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

Suppose we have a submanifold $M^n$ which is embedded in manifold $M^{n+2}$ and $g_{\mu \nu}$ denotes the metric of $M^{n+2}$. We know that the induced metric on the submanifold is defined by

\begin{equation} g_{ab}=\partial_a X^\mu \partial_b X^\nu g_{\mu\nu} \end{equation}

which in my opinion can be imagined as a projection of $g_{\mu\nu}$ onto the submanifold. Now by this metric and also using a normal vector on $M^n$ , we can calculate the intrinsic and extrinsic curvatures.

On the other hand, suppose we first find intrinsic curvature of $M^{n+2}$ and then by constructing

\begin{equation}
h_{\mu\nu}=g_{\mu\nu}-n_\mu \cdot n_\nu
\end{equation}

where $n_\mu$ is the normal vector, we project it onto the submanifold.

And the third case is we know the metric of $M^n$, which we call it $G_{ab}$, and by using it find the curvatures of $M^n$.

Now the question is whether the results of these three procedures are the same or not. By the way, am I right that $G_{a b}$ is different from $g_{ab}$?

Comment: What kind of manifolds? Riemannian? Lorentzian? What is your notion of normal vector, what is your notion of intrinsic and extrinsic curvature? (These terms are usually only used for *surfaces*, i.e. 2D Riemannian manifolds) Could you be looking for the [second fundamental form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_fundamental_form#Hypersurface_in_a_Riemannian_manifold)?

Comment: @ACuriousMind The manifolds are Riemannian. By normal vector, I actually mean a normal vector which is orthognal to tangent space. Second fundamental form (SFF) is another term for extrinsic curvature. And intrinsic curvature is Riemann tensor (or its contractions). I looked for SFF in Wikipedia, but I could just find its definition. Besides, I deal with a codimension two surface which is embedded in a 5 dimensional spacetime. So, it is a 3 dimensional surface.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Codazzi_equations